# Detect main/default language from polyglossia

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

I'm creating a `mystyle.sty` package that sets backgrounds, styles and an introduction. The main .tex file only contains few package loading and options, and of course the main text. One of the options is

```
\setdefaultlanguage{finnish}
```

What I need is that the introduction part (in the package) would change to e.g. english should I change the default language to english too. So the question is:

1. If possible, how do I detect the language that is set by the command `\setdefaultlanguage`?
2. Which would be the simplest way to use this information to choose the appropriate intro?

For the second question, the introtext commands are stored to, say, `\introinfinnish` and `\introinenglish`. Number of different languages are not restricted to two.

A minimal XeLaTeX example (`main.tex`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{finnish} % (english)
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{mystyle}

\begin{document}
  \intropage % from mystyle
  \clearpage

  Something in finnish % (english)
\end{document}
```

and the package (`mystyle.sty`)

```
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\newcommand{\introinfinnish}{Text in finnish...}
\newcommand{\introinenglish}{Text in english...}

% some commands that selects the correct introtext and stores it into \introtext

\newcommand{\intropage}{ % just a sketch
  \@date
  \vfill
  \introtext
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main language is stored in `\xpg@main@language`, so something like the following will do.

```
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\newcommand{\introinfinnish}{Text in finnish...}
\newcommand{\introinenglish}{Text in english...}

% some commands that selects the correct introtext and stores it into \introtext

\newcommand{\intropage}{% just a sketch
  \@date
  \vfill
  \@ifundefined{introin\xpg@main@language}
    {\PackageWarningNoLine{mystyle}{No introduction for `\xpg@main@language'}%
     \introinenglish}
    {\@nameuse{introin\xpg@main@language}}
}
```

As you see, you can use any language you wish, provided you give a definition fo `\introin<language>`.

Please, use `\setmainlanguage` rather than the deprecated `\setdefaultlanguage`

Comment: Very nice and simple solution! Including new intro texts with other languages couldn't be anymore simple. And thanks for the hint on using `\setmainlanguage`.

Comment: It appears nowadays `polyglossia` provides `\languagename` and `\mainlanguagename` (among others) for this functionality.